Integer Solutions to the Equation $(n-1)(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)=nxyz-1$
How can I find all integer solutions for the equation $$(n-1)(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)=nxyz-1$$ for any given positive $n$ where $n≤x≤3n-2$ and $x≤y≤z$?
All attempts by me to solve this problem have so far come short of solving it completely, except for the case where $x=n$ which has at least one solution(x, y, z):
$$(n, n^2, n^4)$$
The case above is in fact the only solution for $n=1$ and a solution for all $n$. There is also a varying amount of solutions where $x=n$ depending on the value of $n$, and that the amount of different values of $x$ which have integer solutions in the range $n≤x≤3n-2$ are rare. In general, most values of $x$ that even do generate a solution in this range generate only one.
Some example values of $n$ for the problem are $n=434701$ and $n=13325313$.

can't we sharpen the limits of $x,y$ and $z$ in terms of $n$? Why $x \leq 3n-2$?

Is there any context to motivate this equation?

Note that one always has $x\equiv y\equiv y\equiv z\equiv n$
. Another observation: all solutions with $x=n$ have the form $y=n^2-1+d$, $z=n^2-1+(n^4-n^2+1)/d$, with $d$ a divisor of $n^4-n^2+1$ satisfying $1\le y\le n^2-1$.

$(n-1)(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)=(nxyz-1)$  -----(1)
Above equation we take, $(n=x)$ & we have:
$(x^2-1)(y+1)(z+1)=(x^2yz-1)$
We take, $(11y=4z)$ & $(z=22x)$
After some algebra we get:
$(3z^2-385z-1452)=0$
$(3z+11)(z-132)=0$
we take, $z=132$
since, $(4z=11y)$ & $(22x=z)$ we get:
$(x,y,z,n)=(6,48,132,6)$
Also equation (1) has more solutions:
$(x,y,z,n)=(7,61,229,7)=(8,100,172,8)$ &
$(x,y,z,n)=(11,133,1237,11)$
